# Issue with sourcing ~/.inputrc, and binding Control-delete to a command

Tags: bash, shell

To source my `~/.inputrc`, I've tried `C-x C-c` and `bind -f  ~/.inputrc`. I'm out of ideas, even after reading the man bash section on `bind`.

---

I have `"\C-Rubout": backward-kill-word` in my `~/.inputrc`. But when I query bash with `bind -q backward-kill-word`, I don't get the output I expect:

```
$ bind -q backward-kill-word
backward-kill-word can be invoked via "\C-rubout", "\e\C-h", "\e\C-?".
```

I think that the wrong capitalization in `rubout` might be  an issue, but no matter how I change my `~/.inputrc` file, I can't get it to work!!

I'm struggling to find a good resource to help me learn how to become less incompetent at the `bind` part of bash... The results I'm getting seem erroneous, but I know better than to be confident about that until I know more about this stuff.

---

I've read through the [gnu manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html), and tried using `\b`, `\d`, and `\177` in lieu of `Rubout`, but none of those worked. The one in the gnu manual ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Sample-Init-File.html#Sample-Init-File)) was pretty neat.

Comment: Are you asking "how can I load `.inputrc` changes into the current shell" or "how do I say `Rubout`"?

Comment: @tripleee I was asking about an issue with getting commands in my `~/.inputrc` to show up properly. I suppose I should change the title, I now know better than to say "I want to source my inputrc", I really want to re-read my init file... In a previous edit of the question, I provided way too much useless information, but that information acted as a segue between the two parts of my question. Removing the spurious information makes the question read poorly. I suppose I should edit the title and re-add the spurious information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default](https://superuser.com/questions/241187/how-do-i-reload-inputrc) binding was not present in terminal. I needed to add `"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file` to my `~/.inputrc`.

*Re-reading an init file will not cause currently bound commands to go away*. I was wrong to assume that deleting a line from my `~/.inputrc` then calling `bind -f ~/.inputrc` would unbind said binding. Thus, This command actually DOES work at re-reading my init file.

---

I was troubleshooting poorly. Since my basics didn't work, all my knowledge was shaky. I was not re-sourcing my readline file, I was re-reading. This is a KEY difference

Additionally, binding a command multiple times in the same file seems to discard all but the last definition. All of my issues with troubleshooting led me to just give up.

Finally, I didn't know that there's both `unix-word-rubout` and `backward-kill-word`. They're 2 distinct commands, but they act the same on my terminal.

---

I realized that I could figure out how to represent `delete` by looking at a command that was bound to delete.:

```
$ bind -q backward-kill-word
backward-kill-word can be invoked via "\e\C-h", "\e\C-?".
```

My terminal [converts delete](https://superuser.com/questions/95626/control-backspace-unix-kill-rubout-for-readline) differently than other terminals, I guess... I thought that `?` was a placeholder for "I am unable to represent this", but that's `�`! I really just needed to use a literal `?`, ASCII code 63.

Anyway, when I placed `"\C-?": unix-word-rubout` in my `~/.inputrc`, everything worked perfectly :)

Comment: My terminal turns inputrc entry `Control-?` into keybinding `C-_`, but inputrc entry `"\C-?"` into keybinding `C-?` (which is what I actually wanted).